# Why is colour of aircraft access panel outlines darker than the rest of the aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-maintenance

I've seen that in nearly every photo of a dark-coloured aircraft (especially prominent in military jets) its panels have a darker colour compared to the rest of the aircraft.

What is the reason for this?

[image: Greek AF F-16]

Comment: Probably they are painted separately, with different batch of paint or at different times. Just like cars, matching paint is hard.

Comment: Do you mean the "gaps" in between? It's probably just dirt or original paint sticking longer in there.

Comment: I don't mean the gaps themselves, which I'd call panel lines (and when eg scale modelling someone would use maybe oils to make them stand out), I mean the difference in colour, also seen on the F-16's tail.

Comment: I can't see what you mean, the panel are light gray because it happens this area of the camouflage pattern is light gray.

Comment: What I mean is that in the grey-camouflaged area I am pointing, for example, you can see the panel outlines being darker. Also, if you see the tail, you'll also see areas where the paint looks darker.